# Lisp isn't reversing my lists

Tags: common-lisp, reverse, clisp

I'm doing some homework in Lisp, using clisp to test, and I'm loading this code and running in in clisp

```
(defun myreverse (thelist)

(reverse thelist)
(print thelist)

(if (equal thelist nil)
    nil
    (if (consp (first thelist))
            (cons (myreverse (reverse (first thelist))) 
                (myreverse (reverse (rest thelist))))
            (cons (first thelist) (myreverse (rest thelist))))))
```

I'm kind of new to Lisp, but this code isn't reversing `thelist` at all, my output is:

```
[18]> (myreverse '(a (b c) d))

(A (B C) D)
((B C) D)
(C B)
(B)
NIL
(D)
NIL
(A (C B) D)
```

The first line of my code says `(reverse thelist)`, why isn't it reversing for the first print statement?  Am I missing something?

Comment: `(null thelist)` is more idiomatic than `(equal thelist nil)` in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `(reverse)` is without side-effects, thus it doesn't reverse the original list, but returns a new, reversed one. This is not so natural in Common Lisp, but expected in Scheme. Nevertheless, here is the doc http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm#reverse

What I think you want is `(nreverse)`.

Comment: Ah ok, so it reverses **(B C)** because when it returns list it actually goes somewhere else in the code (i.e. - reverse-all)?

Comment: Yeah it just prints `thelist`, which happens to be the result of `(reverse (first thelist))` in that case

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much I was really confused there for a second.

Comment: So anyway, what you want is, in the beginning instead of `(reverse thelist)` something like `(nreverse thelist)`

Comment: Yup, I already made the change, working smoothly now.  Thanks.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that even for functions like `(nreverse thelist)` that modify the list in place you have to consume the return value (e.g. `(let ((x (list 1 2 3))) (setf x (nreverse x)))`).